# How to check programatically that 8.3 short path name is enabled on system?

Tags: windows, path, filesystems

I know manually we can enable or disable 8.3 short path name support by setting `NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation`.

But how to read this system information through code? Actually I have to disable some functionality based on whether the system have 8.3 enabled or not.

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered creating a file and then trying to read it using it's 8.3 name?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. No I have not. So you mean I use getshortpathname() and if it returns non NULL length then it means system have 8.3 short path name enabled? I will try this. Thanks

Comment: No I mean you write a file to disk and then try to read it back with its 8.3 name.

Comment: Why not just check the registry?

Comment: Just keep in mind that the current setting for this feature is not necessarily the same as it was in the past or will be in the future, nor does it control the settings on network servers.

Comment: I am using "GetVolumeInformation", but as stated in my below comment "I always get 255 value in *lpMaximumComponentLength, when I toggle between enable and disable 8.3 (using regedit)." Can you please suggest some other method? How to check registry through code?

Answer (score 0):

[`fsutil`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621566.aspx) provides this functionality:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> FSUTIL.EXE 8dot3name query D: 
The volume state is: 0 (8dot3 name creation is enabled). 
The registry state is: 2 (Per volume setting - the default).

Based on the above two settings, 8dot3 name creation is enabled on D:
```

If you want an API, use [`GetVolumeInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which provides this:

> lpMaximumComponentLength [out, optional]
>
> A pointer to a variable that receives the maximum length, in TCHARs,
>   of a file name component that a specified file system supports.
>
> A file name component is the portion of a file name between
>   backslashes. The value that is stored in the variable that
>   *lpMaximumComponentLength points to is used to indicate that a specified file system supports long names. For example, for a FAT file
>   system that supports long names, the function stores the value 255,
>   rather than the previous 8.3 indicator. Long names can also be
>   supported on systems that use the NTFS file system.

Comment: I tested the above mentioned approach. I always get 255 value in *lpMaximumComponentLength, when I toggle between enable and disable 8.3 (using regedit). Query:
PS C:\Windows\system32> FSUTIL.EXE 8dot3name query "CurrentWorkingDir" shows the effect of changes in regedit. Shall I do something else?

Comment: Seconding that comment. This lets you distinguish between a FAT volume without long name support and a FAT volume with long name support, but none of the flags seem to differentiate an NTFS volume without short name support and an NTFS volume with short name support.