# Check 8dot3 support

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-2010

Is there a way in delphi to check if 8.3 is enabled or disabled for a volume? As I am generating a deep folder structure in an automated export I may reach the 260 max path length limit which can be reduced by using 8.3 naming convention.

My aim is to suggesst the user to enable 8.3 on his drive if I exceed the max path length and 8.3 is disabled.

Comment: Interesting question. It's been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479322/how-to-check-programatically-that-8-3-short-path-name-is-enabled-on-system), but the only answer was down-voted. The Microsoft [support article on 8dot3](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/121007/how-to-disable-8-3-file-name-creation-on-ntfs-partitions) suggests there may be a way to check the registry.

Comment: Another possibility is, if you are on Windows 10 build 1607 or later, they've relieved the ridiculous 260 character max path limit, but the user must opt-in. See [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx#maxpath).

Comment: Use the `\\?\` prefix to avoid the 260 limit, and remove the 260 limit with the 1607 opt in. Don't go back in time for 8.3 names. Which won't solve your problem anyway because the limit is applied to the long name not the short name.

Comment: @lurker: I also found the registry entry "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation".

Comment: It seems pretty unlikely that this is determined by a registry setting. After all, it's a property of the volume.

Comment: @lurker Yes, already read it (maybe should have mentioned it). Problem is that its default is set to 2 which means each volume has it´s own property but I haven´t found any way yet, to check the individual volumes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I will have a look into this, thanks!

Comment: formally (begin from win7) exist [`FSCTL_QUERY_PERSISTENT_VOLUME_STATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/fsctl-query-persistent-volume-state) - with this we got [`FILE_FS_PERSISTENT_VOLUME_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_file_fs_persistent_volume_information) and need check `VolumeFlags` to `PERSISTENT_VOLUME_STATE_SHORT_NAME_CREATION_DISABLED`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I understand that logic. I was only following the lead of comments made in the MSDN article: *A registry key allows you to enable or disable the new long path behavior.* That implies to me that one might be able read the registry value to determine if the behavior were enabled (assuming the registry entry is always consistent with the capability).

Comment: I do agree with David's comment that reverting to the ancient ways of 8.3 is probably not a good way to solve the overall problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The opt in is somehow ridicolous. I tried it on multiple computers with 1607 and 1709. Even windows explorer doesn´t support long paths yet, if the flag is set in registry. On 1607 I were not able to delete or open files with names exceeding the limit with the explorer, and on 1709 I still cannot create, rename or move them if the filename length is exceeded.
At least I am able to create those files with a delphi application when using Delphi streams or winapi functions, but only if I add longPathAware node in the manifest. Definitely have to test this on multiple machines...

Comment: Yeah, that's just how it is. 8.3 won't help though will it.

Comment: Fun fact: I just created a C# application to test the some things it always fails with an System.IO.PathTooLongException. That´s sad....But thank you all so far, I guess with all those comment I will be able to create a proper soloution which hopefully will work on older systems, too. If so, I will edit this later into the post.

Comment: Latest versions of the .net RTL allow long paths as an opt in. On the other hand, Delphi's IOUtils is stuck in the dark ages.

Comment: @RbMm Great answer! I was looking for this info for a while. But... do you have any idea why I am getting `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` when querying `PERSISTENT_VOLUME_STATE_SHORT_NAME_CREATION_DISABLED` for volume created by mapping SMB share? (running as admin)

Comment: @C.M. - this is only for *volume created by mapping SMB share* or you got `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` for any volume ?

Comment: @RbMm Local volumes work fine. But if I map a share (even local one) -- can't get this flag. Running in user mode as admin.

Comment: @RbMm you could observe it with `fsutil` too -- mount a share and try `fsutil 8dot3name query <volume>`